# Successful national digital currencies

Tags: altcoin, airdrop

Are there any successful stories about coins created specifically for a country? (pre mined and drop)

I have seen cases like Auroracoin, but I want to know if there has been a success story.

Answer (score 3):

Most altcoins have done very poorly. You can see the list of relatively successful ones [here](https://coinmarketcap.com/). There isn't a country coin that's got a market cap over a million. I would say there hasn't been a success story.